# Unhandled Memory Exception using OpenCV sqrt

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my following code:

```
void filter() {
    Mat kern = (Mat_<char>(3,3) << -1, 0, 1,
                                   -1, 0, 1,
                                   -1, 0, 1);

    Mat kern2 = (Mat_<char>(3,3) <<  1, 1, 1,
                                     0, 0, 0,
                                    -1, -1, -1);


    Mat I = imread("lena.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    imshow("Lena1", I);
    Mat J,K;


    filter2D(I, J, I.depth(), kern);
    filter2D(I, K, I.depth(), kern2);

    imshow("Lena2", J);
    imshow("Lena3", K);

    pow(J,2,J);
    pow(K,2,K);
    Mat X = J + K;
    imshow("Test1", X);
    sqrt(X,X);
    imshow("Test2", X);

    waitKey(0);


}
```

Just simply trying to display the gradient of the image. However, at the `sqrt(X,X)`, a unhandled memory exception occurs. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the declaration of `sqrt`?

Comment: i get: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F) in cv::pow,

Comment: @berak with my exact code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be a problem of datatype. `sqrt` expect floating point images ([documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sqrt#sqrt)), but from your code, I think they are 8-bit images.

Try to replace `I.depth()` by `CV_32F` in your call to `filter2D`.

Comment: imshow("Test2", X *(1.0/255)); // just adapt the range

Comment: I think `imshow` expect a [0,1] range for floating point images and [0,255] for 8-bits images. So either you convert the final image back to 8-bit using `convertTo`, or you divide by 255 to get a [0,1] range. @berak beat me to it ;)

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, both of you. Sorry for the beginners questions. Back to the tutorial for me :)

Comment: no reason to be sorry, you're obviously improving ;)